# change color of listview in android by custom adapter

Tags: android

Below is my mainactivity java code I have a json file which returns the following values.

```
[
 {
  "COMPONENT": "xxxx",
  "FLAG": "T",
  "SAMPLINGPOINT": "dddd"
 },
 {
  "COMPONENT": "yyyyy",
  "FLAG": "F",
  "SAMPLINGPOINT": "ggggg"
 },
 {
  "COMPONENT": "xxxx",
  "FLAG": "F",
  "SAMPLINGPOINT": "dddd"
 },
 {
  "COMPONENT": "xxxx",
  "FLAG": "T",
  "SAMPLINGPOINT": "dddd"
 }

]
```

On display if the json value FLAG:T then the `ListView` color should be red else if FLAG:F then green. Where do I put the custom adapter and how?? any help??

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String TAG = "Response";
    TextView responseText;
    Button bt;
    EditText celcius;
    String getCel;
    SoapPrimitive resultString;
    String color, item;
    String str = "<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>";
   //private static final String name = "ID_NUMERIC";
   // private static final String test = "TEST";
    private static final String component = "COMPONENT";
   // private static final String units = "UNITS";
    private static final String value = "VALUE";
    private static final String flag = "FLAG";
    //private static final String color = "color";
    //private static final String samplingpoint = "SAMPLINGPOINT";
    JSONArray Response = null;
    String jsonObject_string ;
    String jArray;
    ListView list;
    TextView vers;
    TextView name;
    TextView flg;
    TextView api;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public void calculate() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "";
        String METHOD_NAME = "";
        String NAMESPACE = "";
        String URL = "";

        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("SmapleID", getCel);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            //Log.i(TAG, "Result SmapleID: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
        celcius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                getCel = celcius.getText().toString();
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();


            }
        });

    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            calculate();
            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //calculate();

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,R.layout.list_child,new String[] {component, value, flag, color }, new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.vers, R.id.flg});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);    

             oslist.clear();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String data = "";
            String data1 = "";
            String data2 = "";
            String data3 = "";
            String data4 = "";
            String data5 = "";
            String jsonStr = resultString.toString();

            //Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {

              try 

            {

              JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

               // String name = json_obj.getString("ID_NUMERIC");
               // String test = json_obj.getString("    TEST");
                String component = json_obj.getString("COMPONENT");
                //String units = json_obj.getString("UNITS");
                String value = json_obj.getString("VALUE");
                String flag = json_obj.getString("FLAG");
               if ("F".equalsIgnoreCase(flag));{
                   color = "red";
               }
                //data = name;
               // data1 = test + ", ";
                data2 = component;
               // data3 = units;
                data4 =  value;
                data =  flag;

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("COMPONENT", data2);
                map.put("VALUE", data4);
                map.put("FLAG", data);

                oslist.add(map);

        }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                // handle exception
            }

        }
          // return null;
        }

    }}
}
```

From the comment

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist, R.layout.list_child, 
            new String[]{component, value, flag}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.vers, R.id.flg});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Please share custom Adapter code also

Comment: well..thts what i want..the code and where and how to put it i basically need to change the color of my listview based in the json value using custom adapter

Comment: But you have already `SimpleAdapter` class which is Adapter for ListView. please share `SimpleAdapter` class code

Comment: you can use BaseAdapter for that you can check this answer for BaseAdapter and in base adapter getView method you can change view http://stackoverflow.com/a/28104066/1140237

Comment: okay...so then how do i filter out the json value from the file above using this adapter..

Comment: @ThunderGoli: dude, share `SimpleAdapter` class code then we will tell you

Comment: ok  ρяσѕρєя..here is the SimpleAdapter class code
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,R.layout.list_child,new String[] {component, value, flag}, new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.vers, R.id.flg});
list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: waitin fr yr answer  ρяσѕρєя plzz

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK `SimpleAdapter` is android class not custom class by  @thunder Goli

Answer (score 0):

Use below adapter for reference.
I have changed colors for every alternate row. Change it by putting condition as appropriate.

Make sure to create osList before setting adapter on the list & replace stockCursor with osList.

```
private class StockAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{       
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return stockCursor.getCount();      
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(StockDetailsActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.stock_details_list_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.model_name_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_name);
            viewHolder.model_type_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_type_icon);
            viewHolder.model_type_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_type_desc);
            viewHolder.model_stock_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_stock_value);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        stockCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        if(position % 2 == 1)
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.john_deere_green40));
        else
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.john_deere_green60));

        return v;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView model_name_tv;
        public ImageView model_type_iv;                 
        public TextView model_type_tv;              
        public TextView model_stock_tv;             
    }        
}
```

Comment: i am sorry..i am not able to understand as to how to use this reference in my code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setViewBinder` method for customization list

you can edit your code in `onPostExecute`

```
 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,R.layout.list_child,new String[] {component, value, flag, color }, new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.vers, R.id.flg});
 adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {

        switch (key) {
           case R.id.name:
             //example
             TextView tvName = (TextView) view;
                // hear you can customize your textview as per your req.
             tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#053d6e'>"
                        + /*get you value from JSON*/  + "</font> "));
             return true;
            case R.id.vers: 
             return true;
            case R.id.flg:
             return true;

        default:
            break;
        }
      return false;

    });
}
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: so for changing the color of the json value flg what code do i write milapTank

Comment: @ThunderGoli see my update `tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#053d6e'>"
                        + //get you value from JSON  + "</font> "));`

Comment: thnx milap but there is a syntax error showing at the end of your code before the line

list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: You can get hint from this code may be there is my mistake in typo but you can solve syntax error  BTW can you tell me more about that ?

Comment: it says Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Comment: there is switch case problem are  you able to solve this ?

Comment: first of all dont copy my code use editor hint and write code from my code DONT COPY please

Comment: @ThunderGoli  i have update my question you can get it

Comment: i can give you technical solution but syntax error you have solve buddy  this is basic :)

Comment: maan still gettin syntax error 
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
newas u hlpd yr best milapTank. ..thnx buddy

Answer (score 0):

Please check below posted code for custom listadapter & i have mentioned things in comment inside code block.

```
private class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        int totalDisplayDatasize = 0;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> codeLeanChapterList;

        public ListViewCustomAdapter(Context context,
                                     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> codeLeanChapterList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.codeLeanChapterList = codeLeanChapterList;
            if (this.codeLeanChapterList != null)
                totalDisplayDatasize = this.codeLeanChapterList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // this could be one of the reason for not showing listview.set
            // total data length for count
            return totalDisplayDatasize;
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int i) {
            return this.codeLeanChapterList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        private class Holder {
            TextView textView1, textView2;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder = null;
            View view = convertView;
                /*
                 * First time for row if view is not created than inflate the view
                 * and create instance of the row view Cast the control by using
                 * findview by id and store it in view tag using holder class
                 */
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                // / No need to create LayoutInflater instance in
                // constructor

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(
                        R.layout.listitem, parent,false);

                holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                    /*
                     * Here view next time it wont b null as its created and
                     * inflated once and in above if statement its created. And
                     * stored it in view tag. Get the holder class from view tag
                     */
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

            }
            holder.textView1.setText("COMPONENT: "
                    + codeLeanChapterList.get(position).get("COMPONENT"));

            holder.textView2.setText("VALUE: "
                    + codeLeanChapterList.get(position).get("VALUE"));
            String flagChar = codeLeanChapterList.get(position).get("FLAG");
            if ("T".equalsIgnoreCase(flagChar)) {
                holder.textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                /// in this i have given background color to textview
                //you can change it to listitem layout or whatever object you want
            } else if ("F".equalsIgnoreCase(flagChar)) {
                holder.textView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                /// in this i have given background color to textview
                //you can change it to listitem layout or whatever object you want
            } else {
                // keep this case if its required
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

listitem is listitem layout which has 3 textview in your case it will be your listview layout and based on that you need to change getView method and holder class too. if you are new with this things thn please check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html
http://ocddevelopers.com/2014/extend-baseadapter-instead-of-arrayadapter-for-custom-list-items/

Answer (score 0):

public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter{

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data 


public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.data = arr;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        return data.get(position);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        return position;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return data.size();
    }
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflat = ctx.getLayoutInflater();
        final Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.listview_desc_discover, null, false);
            holder = new Holder();

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        if (data.get(position).get("FLAG").equals(“F”)) {
            // set green color to  convertView
        } else if(data.get(position).get("FLAG").equals(“T”)){
           // set green red to  convertView 
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
```

}